# View last N to M Git commits in vimdiff

Tags: git, bash

Here is a one-liner that illustrates what I'd like to do:

```
revs=(2 3); f=index.html; vimdiff -d <(git show HEAD~2:"$f") <(git show HEAD~3:"$f")
```

How can I use the array revs and avoid hard-coding?

Answer (score 2):

You can access bash array elements with `${array_variable[index]}`. Array indices in bash start at 0.

So

```
revs=(2 3); f=index.html; vimdiff <(git show HEAD~${revs[0]}:"$f") <(git show HEAD~${revs[1]}:"$f")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function a while ago to diff against the repository in SVN - basically the goal was "Write the repo version to a file, then open vim diff, then delete the files"

```
function diff(){
    file=${!#}
    tmpfile=/tmp/repo/${!#}
    mkdir -p `dirname $tmpfile`
    svn cat $@ > $tmpfile
    vimdiff $file $tmpfile
    rm -rf /tmp/repo/
}
```

I'm not used to git, but here's a thought:

```
function multiDiff(){
    fname=$1
    shift
    files=""
    while (( "$#" ))
    do
        tmpfile="/tmp/repo/$1/$fname"
        mkdir -p `dirname $tmpfile`
        git show HEAD~$1:$fname > $tmpfile
        files="$files $tmpfile"
        shift
    done
    vimdiff $files
    rm -rf /tmp/repo
}
```

The function saves a version of each file to the temporary directory, then diffs all the files.  it would be invoked `multidiff index.html 2 3 4`  You could even write a convenience functions to do sequences:

```
function multiDiffSeq(){
    multiDiff $1 `seq $2 $3`
}
```

which would translate `multiDiffSeq index.html 2 4` to `multiDiff index.html 2 3 4`.

This biggest upside of this configuration is that the file's extension is preserved, which means that your syntax Highlighting is preserved.

If there're some errors in the git handling, sorry - I don't currently have a git repo to practice against.  Hope those help.