# git whatchanged with vimdiff

Tags: git, patch, vimdiff

I would like to see the changes I am pushing with `vimdiff`. [I can see the changes before commit](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/git-diff-with-vimdiff/) with `$ git diff` configuring `vimdiff` to `~/.gitconfig`.

After commits, I can see the commits with `--patch` switch on `whatchanged` command,

`$ git whatchanged origin/master.. --patch`

But, with this command the changes are displayed in default vim, and I want to see the changes in `vimdiff` with two vertical columns.

### Reference

Stackoverflow question [View last N to M Git commits in vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404197/view-last-n-to-m-git-commits-in-vimdiff) seems to address my question(at least the title), but I got no clue with the answers there(maybe too nerdish).

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+whatchanged+patch+with+vimdiff&oq=git+whatchanged+patch+with+vimdiff&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.521j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) didn't show me proper results.

Answer (score 0):

It is new to me too, so I tried to adapt the code from [View last N to M Git commits in vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404197/view-last-n-to-m-git-commits-in-vimdiff).

```
f=myFile.txt
vimdiff <(git show HEAD^1:"$f") $f
```

So simply feed vimdiff both files, this shows the last commit (iow. `git show`) for one file. The other thread shows how to do it for a range of commits.

I suppose whatschanged and other frontend commands would need some additional options to iterate their diffs per file, but I have not looked at this.